# Entity Framework - Erro ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou recebendo os seguinte erro ao tentar atualizar uma entidade no EF:

{"Um objeto com uma chave que corresponde à chave do objeto fornecido não pôde ser localizado no ObjectStateManager. Verifique se os valores de chave do objeto fornecido correspondem aos valores de chave do objeto no qual alterações devem ser aplicadas."}

O erro ocorre dentro do método abaixo ao chama o Update:

```
 private void ModificarStatus(int id,
                              bool validarMudancaParaCritico, 
                              TipoMedicao tipoMedicao)
    {
        MedidorAutomatico medidorAuto = BpMedidorAutomatico.MedidorAutomaticoPorId(id);
        if (medidorAuto.StatusConformidade != (short)StatusConformidade.Critico &&
            medidorAuto.StatusConformidade != (short)StatusConformidade.Outros)
        {
            medidorAuto.StatusConformidade = (short)StatusConformidade.Atencao;
        }
        if (validarMudancaParaCritico)
        {
            if (medidorAuto.StatusConformidade != (short)StatusConformidade.Outros)
                medidorAuto.StatusConformidade = (short)StatusConformidade.Critico;
        }

        BpMedidorAutomatico.Update(medidorAuto);
    }

    public override MedidorAutomatico Update(MedidorAutomatico entity)
    {
        MedidorAutomatico medidor = base.Update(entity);
        return medidor;
    }
```

Esse método nos testes que estou fazendo é chamado 2 vezes, na primeira não tive problemas ao fazer o update do registro no banco, na segunda chamada dispara o erro. O que quero saber é se tem uma forma fácil de rastrear o problema? O que posso verificar no código para me ajudar a localizar o erro?

Comment: Tenta apenas adicionar um `base.SaveChanges();` após o `base.Update(entity);`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, como toda a execução estava atrelada a uma Transaction externa, ao alterar o método de Update para usar o TransactionScope o problema sumiu.

```
    public override MedidorAutomatico Update(MedidorAutomatico entity)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            MedidorAutomatico medidor = base.Update(entity);
            transaction.Complete();
            return medidor;
        }
    }
```